# Update custom LWC table if record is updated

Tags: lightning-web-components, table, connected-callback

I am new to LWC and here is my problem:

I have table and values needs to be updated once the record fields are updated. Here is the code:

1.Apex Class

```
    public with sharing class LWCShowSpendigs {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Requisition__c> getRequisitionFields(Id recordId){
        return [SELECT Id, Estimated_Amount__c, Received_Invoices__c, Remaining_Amount__c, Split_Total__c,
                Split_1__c, Split_2__c, Split_3__c, Split_4__c,
                Estimated_Amount_Split_1__c, Estimated_Amount_Split_2__c,Estimated_Amount_Split_3__c, Estimated_Amount_Split_4__c,
                Received_Invoices_Split_1__c, Received_Invoices_Split_2__c, Received_Invoices_Split_3__c, Received_Invoices_Split_4__c,
                Remaining_Amount_Split_1__c, Remaining_Amount_Split_2__c, Remaining_Amount_Split_3__c, Remaining_Amount_Split_4__c
        From Requisition__c where Id =: recordId];

    }
}
```

2. JS

```
    import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
    
    import getRequisitionFields from '@salesforce/apex/LWCShowSpendigs.getRequisitionFields';
    
    export default class LwcShowSpendings extends LightningElement {
    
        @api recordId;
        @track requisitionFields;
    
        connectedCallback() {
            this.isLoading = true;
            getRequisitionFields({ recordId: this.recordId })
                .then(result => {
                    this.requisitionFields = result;
    
                })
                .catch( error => {
                     console.log(error);
                });
        }
    }
```

3. HTML

```
<template>
        <template if:true={requisitionFields}>
            <h1> Calculations </h1>
            <div class="tableDiv">
                <table aria-describedby="spending-list" class="slds-table  slds-table_bordered ">
                    <!--Header of the table-->
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-6 " scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate " title=""></div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-6 " scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate " title="Q 1 ">Quarter 1</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-6 " scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate " title="Q 2">Quarter 2</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-6" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate " title="Q 3">Quarter 3</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-6" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate " title="Q 4">Quarter 4</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-6" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate " title="FY">Fiscal Year</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!--Body of the table-->
                    <tbody>
                    <template for:each={requisitionFields} for:item="item">
                        <tr key={item.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div class="slds-truncate " title="Requisition Split">Requisition Split</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Split_1__c}%
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Split_2__c}%
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Split_3__c}%
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Split_4__c}%
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Split_Total__c}%
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr key={item.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate " title="Estimated amount">Estimated amount</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Estimated_Amount_Split_1__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Estimated_Amount_Split_2__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Estimated_Amount_Split_3__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Estimated_Amount_Split_4__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Estimated_Amount__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr key={item.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate " title="Received Invoices">Received Invoices</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Received_Invoices_Split_1__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Received_Invoices_Split_2__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Received_Invoices_Split_3__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Received_Invoices_Split_4__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Received_Invoices__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr key={item.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate " title="Remaining amount">Remaining amount</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Remaining_Amount_Split_1__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Remaining_Amount_Split_2__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Remaining_Amount_Split_3__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Remaining_Amount_Split_4__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                                <div>
                                    {item.Remaining_Amount__c}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your own apex class use a wire function with [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record).

Values will get updated out of the box.